# Добавление нового сайта в VPS и его безопасность

Tags: php, apache, сервер

Развернул сервер. Создал в директории `/var/www/` папку `/var/www/domains/`. Там создал папку для сайта, то есть имя папки соответствует названию домена.. Например, `/var/www/domains/mysite.ru/`...

мой `vhost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.ru
    ServerAlias www.mysite.ru

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/mysite.ru
</VirtualHost>
```

но если я укажу абсолютный путь от моего сервера, то есть `ip_server/domain/mysite.ru/`, **то я попадаю на сайт**... скажите, так и должно быть? если нет - как это исправить?

также, будут ли у Вас какие-то советы по безопасности, при добавления сайта на сервер? что нужно знать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Удалить в апаче хост, который там есть по умолчанию, не?

Comment: а что если у меня несколько сайтов?

Comment: Добавить хост для каждого, очевидно)